# How to create similar interface like the Photo application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios

How do I start an application which has a similar interface like the Photo application that ships with the iPhone? Specifically an interface with a `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` both present in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use both tab and navigation together, you create a tab bar application and change the class of its views from UIViewController to NavigationController. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/), it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the Three20 open-source iPhone framework.  More specifically their TTPhotoViewController.

[github - Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20)

[image]